# Is there a way to copy a class's source to string, in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {
// properties and methods here
}
```

Ideally I'd like to send the entire class to a string so I can render it in a view. The best way I can think of doing this, is to have a build script run and send it all to static text files, then reference those text files in the code. Is there a better way to do this? I'd like to be able to say:

```
return View(SomeClass.SourceToString());
```

I'm hoping I'm not missing a really obvious way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you have access to the source file?

Comment: Yes I have access to the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# is compiled into MSIL. There is no direct way to access the original source other than referencing the original source file.

Comment: I suppose you could chuck the source code into a resource at compile time, and grab it from there. You could use some name pattern to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to enumerate all the members of the class and emit each member's declaration/definition to a `StringBuilder`, and then return the built string.

Comment: it will not be source of class

Comment: that won't give you the source code, strictly speaking. (As the name implies, "source code" is the source from which the compiler generated the MSIL. Reflection can't give you that, it can only "compile" the MSIL into C# code. So you get C# code that is *equivalent* to the source code, but it's not identical to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is nothing straightforward, and the reflection will give you a "reinterpreted" form of the code, with different structure, no comments, no body for methods...
Maybe you could save a "copy" of your code using a post-build script and resolve it when the SourceToString method is called.

I think you should really explain why you would a such like thing ? Maybe we will be able to suggest you a better solution.